# npm attempting to install outdated package

Tags: node.js, npm

Previously my company had been using `node-sass` v3.13.1 which is out of date and will return a 404 now.  I updated it a while back to load v4.9.4.  It was a pain and it kept wanting to reload 3.13.1 but eventually it worked, I forget how. Anyways, now I am on a new computer and reinstalling the npm packages using `npm install` and it is AGAIN searching for this v3.13.1.  This stupid thing just doesn't die.  Of course it fails with a 404.

Things I've done:

- I confirmed that the only node-sass reference in package.json is 4.9.4.
- I confirmed that the only node-sass reference in package-lock.json is 4.9.4
- I ran `npm cache clean --force`
- I double checked that my git bash is set to the correct directory when running npm install
- I double checked that the correct package.json and package-lock.json are in that same directory
- I ran `npm install node-sass@4.9.4` and it responded saying it was loading a cached binary found at .... then it started loading node-sass@3.13.1

I'm at a loss.  How do I kill this thing once and for all to never ever allow npm to try to load this stupid outdated package?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution.  The problem was that I had another package `gulp-sass` that was out of date.  I updated it to `3.0.0` in the package.json and it worked.  The solution I found was here:

https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/issues/4430